# How can I add an Icon to to Box Decoration?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to add an Icon to Box Decoration like this you are seeing images on left side.

[image]

How do I add this with box decoration

Here is the code:

```html
    Container(
             width: 307,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
               shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
             ),
           child: CountryListPick(
            onChanged: (list){
              print(list?.name);
                },
              theme: CountryTheme(
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                isShowFlag:true,
                isShowCode: false,
                isShowTitle:true,
                isDownIcon: true,
                showEnglishName: true,
              ),
            ),
           ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a row as a children of container

```
Container(
                  width: 307,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/cover_placeholder.png",
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 12,),
                      Flexible(
                        child: CountryListPick(
                          onChanged: (list){
                            print(list?.name);
                          },
                          theme: CountryTheme(
                            labelColor: Colors.white,
                            isShowFlag:true,
                            isShowCode: false,
                            isShowTitle:true,
                            isDownIcon: true,
                            showEnglishName: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Just one question Is there a way to change the label color? I am using a popular library(country_list_pick) to get the list of countries

Comment: @mob_dev I explored the country_list_pick library issue list in github but currently they don't have any option to change the text/label color. But you can try this thread though I haven't tried this.

https://github.com/hifiaz/country-list-pick/issues/30

Answer (score 1):

You can use this widget for a textfield with boxdecoration and icon:

```
TextFormField(
          key: Key(key),
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(icon), // <-- left icon
            hintText: hintText,
            border: OutlineInputBorder( //<--- decoration border
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
            filled: true,
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
So you can use SizedBox or Container - 
     SizedBox(
              width: 300.0,
              height: 120.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        type: MaterialType.transparency,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 5.0),
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                    color: Colors.green[50],
                                  ),
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                    color: Colors.red[700],
                                    highlightColor: Colors.red,
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```